# How to remove part of string data from strings which are mutually dependent in java

Tags: java, javascript, string

I have two string arrays in javascript like

```
var names = [name1, name2, name3, name4];
var values = [value1, value2, value3, value4];
```

I need to send these values to backend. And I am sending as follows

```
var nameString = "name1,name2,name3,name4";
var valuesString = "value1,value2,value3,value4";
```

Then i will iterate it over a map in java. My problem is if i want to remove name from name string, that corresponding value from valueString should also remove. How to do this in java side in an optimized way.

```
Ex: If i want to remove name3, then new strings should be like following:
  In Java side:   
     String nameString = "name1,name2,name4";
     String valueString = "value1,value2,value4";
```

Comment: Why dont you store it as an JSON object? Since it seems names and values have a one-to-one relationship it would make perfect sense. There are some libraries available that allow you to use JSON in Java http://www.json.org Then you could just remove the property from the JSON object and everything is fine.

Comment: I need to set these nameString, valueString to a java bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript:

```
var data = {name1:value1, name2:value1, name3:value1, name4:value1};
```

(quoted if needed), the send the object as JSON, and parse it in java.
http://www.json.org/java/

i'm not a java dev, so in cant help you so much with specific code, but the method its the same for all languajes

Comment: +1 excellent method, but I'd suggest to use a more modern and easy to use library like [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Answer (score 1):

in java you could do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nameString = "name1,name2,name3,name4";
    String valueString = "value1,value2,value3,value4";

    nameString = removeSection(nameString, 2);
    valueString = removeSection(valueString, 2);

    System.out.println(nameString);
    System.out.println(valueString);

}

private static String removeSection(String val, int del){
    String[] a = val.split(",");
    String[] b = new String[a.length-1];

    System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0,del);
    System.arraycopy(a,del+1,b,del,a.length-1-del);

    val = arrayToString(b);

    return val;
}

private static String arrayToString(String[] a){
    String newStr = "";
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(i==0){
            newStr += a[i];
        }else{
            newStr += ","+a[i];
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}
```